# Pytest - How to use one fixture for several conftest files issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytest

I have several pytest suites and each of them has almost the same conftest file. As the conftest files contain kind of duplicate code and as they might get bigger over time and the number of suites also may increase, I have decided to move the conftest fixtures to another module in a certain path and 'import' it using `pytest_plugins` variable to the conftest files.

There is one issue. There is one fixture that depends on a local variable of the conftest files. How do I move the fixture to another another module and also force it to use the local variable of the conftest file?

new_conftest_module.py

```
var = 1

@pytest.fixture(scope="session", autouse=True)
def session_init():
    do_something(var)
```

test_dir1/conftest.py

```
pytest_plugins = ['new_conftest_module']
var = 2
```

test_dir2/conftest.py

```
pytest_plugins = ['new_conftest_module']
var = 3
```

This is a dummy example, but as you can see the issue is that `var` variable is particular to every conftest file, but the fixture that uses it is the same. Is there a workaround I could use in order to have the fixture in a common module while using particular `var` value for every suite?

Comment: Have a look at [ddt](http://ddt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which might be what you want (though it uses `unittest` not `py.test`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

conftest.py can reference any fixture that is in other conftests below it, giving you the ability to define the same fixture with different return value in different suite folders. Just make var a fixture that you set in a separate conftest for each group of tests, and the conftest in the root directory will always use the right one for each test.

rootdir

- conftest.py
- test_group_1

  - conftest.py
- test_group_2

  - conftest.py

test_group_1/conftest.py

```
@fixture
def group_var():
    return 1
```

test_group_2/conftest.py

```
@fixture
def group_var():
    return 2
```

rootdir/conftest.py

```
@fixture
def do_something(group_var):
    print(group_var)
```

Each test will now print the var that is set in the conftest for its own test group, even if run parallelized.

Comment: can you please give a specific example?

Comment: @rbs Did this answer your question?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but this does not really apply. What I want to do is to 'import' from the root conftest using pytest_plugins variable to to other subfolders conftests. And this implies that the root conftest must have a different name then "conftest", so it is just like a regular module. If it is also named conftest, it will result in an error.

Comment: My question is why do you wany to import conftest? That does not sound like a good way to solve your problem, but maybe I just don't understand your use case.

Comment: The use case is that I have many test suites that all have the same conftest, duplicated in each test folder. So I want to change that and have one conftest (not an actual conftest like I said) and the test directories conftests to import that module using the pytest_plugins variable

Comment: @rbs Last question - are all these test suites in the same repository?

Comment: Yes they are. The directory structure is similar to the one in the description.

Comment: @rbs Then why don't you just place a single conftest.py in the top directory? All tests will reference it and you don't need to duplicate it.

Comment: I have implemented your solution as it serves the purpose. But I have one aditional issue. Would you have any idea how can I reference a fixture from a below conftest from a hook like pytest_runtest_setup from the master conftest? Or maybe a workaround for this as I can't figure it out...

Comment: You need to set custom setup per sub directory in the conftest.py for that directory (or not when you don't need any special setup). Don't set pytest_runtest_setup in your root conftest. What are you trying to setup for each test?

Comment: Ok, so I need to move pytest_runtest_setup to the directory conftest. I use pytest_runtest_setup for skiping tests if a condition based on a test variable and an external variable is True. I have access to the test variable from item._request.function.func_globals .